# endless for loop when calling a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I have 2 function, `insertInto` for inserting data from ma array in a Mysql database, and `checkRow` where I check if the current row from my array already exists. The structure of the array `tableArray` is $tableArray["Tabelle2"][number of row][number of column]. However, always when I refresh the page it inserts more rows in the database and avoid to check if the row already exists.

the **function insertInto**:

```
function insertInto($i, $tableArray, $conn){ //insert into db
    $dateFormated = split('/', $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][3]);
    $date = $dateFormated[2].'-'.$dateFormated[0].'-'.$dateFormated[1];

    $insertInto = "insert into Excel(Arbeitsplatz, Auftragsart, Auftragsnummer, Datum, Tageszeit, Erklaerung, Beschreibung, AG, StdArt, Anwender) 
    values('".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][0]."', '".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][1]."', '".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][2]."', '".$date."', 
    '".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][4]."', '".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][5]."', '".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][6]."', 
    '".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][7]."', '".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][8]."', '".$tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][9]."')";
    if($conn->query($insertInto) === true){echo "Datensatz Nr. ".$i." wurde eingefuegt.<br />";}else{echo "Datensatz Nr. ".$i." wurde nicht eingefuegt.<br />";}
}
```

the **function checkRow**:

```
function checkRow($i, $tableArray, $conn){ //if(... == ...)
    $count = "select count(*) from Excel;";
    $res = $conn->query($count);
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $rowsNum = $row["count(*)"];    
    if($rowsNum == 0){
        insertInto($i, $tableArray, $conn);
    } else {
        for($b = 1; $b <= $rowsNum; $b++){
            $select = "select * from Excel where ExcelID = '".$b."'";
            $result = $conn->query($select);
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            if($tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][0] == $row["Arbeitsplatz"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][1] == $row["Auftragsart"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][2] == $row["Auftragsnummer"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][4] == $row["Tageszeit"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][5] == $row["Erklaerung"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][6] == $row["Beschreibung"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][7] == $row["AG"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][8] == $row["StdArt"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][9] == $row["Anwender"]){
                echo "Datensatz ist bereits vorhanden.<br />";
            } else {
                insertInto($i, $tableArray, $conn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the loop where I call the function checkRow:

```
for($g = 1; $g <= count($tableArray["Tabelle2"]); $g++){
    checkRow($g, $tableArray, $conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was in the function `checkRow();`, I always checked the current row from my array with 1 row in the Mysql database, and not all of them. By adding `$counter`, which counts always + 1 if the current row in the array is not the same as the row in the database, I solved the problem.

updated **function checkRow**:

```
function checkRow($i, $tableArray, $conn){ //if(... == ...)
            $count = "select count(*) from Excel;";
            $res = $conn->query($count);
            $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
            $rowsNum = $row["count(*)"];
            $counter = 0;

            if($rowsNum == 0){
                insertInto($i, $tableArray, $conn);
                } elseif($rowsNum > 0) {
                    for($b = 1; $b <= $rowsNum; $b++){
                        $select = "select * from Excel where ExcelID = '".$b."'";
                        $result = $conn->query($select);
                        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                        if($tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][0] == $row["Arbeitsplatz"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][1] == $row["Auftragsart"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][2] == $row["Auftragsnummer"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][4] == $row["Tageszeit"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][5] == $row["Erklaerung"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][6] == $row["Beschreibung"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][7] == $row["AG"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][8] == $row["StdArt"] && $tableArray["Tabelle2"][$i][9] == $row["Anwender"]){
                                echo "Datensatz ist bereits vorhanden.<br />";
                            } else {$counter++;}
                    }
                    if($counter == $rowsNum){
                        insertInto($i, $tableArray, $conn);
                        $counter = 0;
                    }
                }
        }
```